# Fixing "spatial index grid size is invalid" without Recalculate button

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, file-geodatabase

I've got a python script that is connecting a squence of points to make lines, and putting them into a feature class (based on [answers to my previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61102/create-line-from-two-points-two-different-feature-class)). It works wonderfully on a small area that I was using to debug and test (~25 meters, 20 points), but then when I put it into a real-world scenario (~1000 meters, ~500 points), it breaks.

```
The spatial index grid size is invalid.
```

Looking into the ArcGIS help suggestions to fix/prevent that, [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000046000000) suggests recalculating the spatial index grid ([directions here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n0000001s000000)), but my polyline feature class doesn't have that option when I am in the "Indexes" tab -- there's no "Recalculate" button at all, and the "Delete" button is grayed out. So how can I fix the error? (I tried simply deleting my original feature class and making a new one, on the theory that my original "little" test case was setting the spatial index grid too small; however, even with a brand-new feature class, I have the same error.)

The problem is more specifically the number of dots I'm trying to connect during one run of the script -- less than ~50 is fine, more than ~100 is not...*

ArcGIS for Desktop with Advanced level license, data stored in feature class in a file geodatabase.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: It sounds like you are in a good position to be able to post a working code snippet here that reproducibly demonstrates this problem.  The same error is mentioned in  [Esri Technical Article 35007](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35007).

Comment: This is from over a year ago; I know what script I was working on and talking about, but will need to look around for quite a while to find the version that was dysfunctional. I'll get it eventually, though :)

Answer (score 8):

I recently ran into this problem and was able to solve it by deleting the spatial index on the feature I was trying to edit.  For reference I'm working with features in WGS84 (EPSG:4326).

Comment: Such a simple solution. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem for the first time while creating polygons around GPS GCPs. Everything was fine while circling the sub-provinces or suburbs. When I started doing the entire provinces this thing showed up. First I tried everything e.g. vector conversions, shp to feature class, coverage, etc.Then I realized that if the clicked vertexes are close one another, a polygon can be completed. Having known this I drew a small polygon inside the intended location, then edited the vertexes in small aerial increments until the entire province's circumference is reached. The projection was Geographic.