# Error when saving into .gdb file

Tags: qgis, gdal, file-geodatabase, spatial-index

I am supposed to copy a shapefile into an existing database (*.gdb) using QGIS.
There is no problem opening the database, neither when pasting the elements into it.

However, once I try to save the edits, I get the following error :

```
Could not commit changes to layer CDN_GDB_Nozon_v28 CDN_CE_CCO

Errors: ERROR: 155 feature(s) not added.

Provider errors:

OGR error creating feature -312: Failed at writing Row to Table in CreateFeature. (The spatial index grid size is invalid.)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61523/fixing-spatial-index-grid-size-is-invalid-without-recalculate-button), this error in ArcGis is caused by a bad spatial index (too far away from the actual data). It is however (as fas as I tried) not possible to delete a spatial index in a .gdb from Qgis.

The workaround is to manually delete the files using your file explorer. Navigate to the gdb folder, and erase all the files with the *.gdbindexes extension. [reference here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/modifying-a-spatial-index.htm)

Then re-open the database in Qgis, with the ability to save the edits in the geodatabase.